# I am playing a “the Lord of the Rings” game

Tags: sentence-structure, definite-article, names, quotations

Which of these sentences is correct?

> **I am playing a “the Lord of the Rings” game.**

VS

> **I am playing a “Lord of the Rings” game.**

*And which of these is correct?*

> **I want to watch some “the Lord of the Rings.”**

VS

> **I want to watch some “Lord of the Rings.”**

I am having a dilemma here. I feel like we could say these sentences with or without the article. Normally, the books/franchise is called “**the** Lord of the Rings”, but in these sentences it might be weird to use **the**. But using the proper intonation/pause we may get away with it? I don’t know. What do you think?

**Context:** In the first pair of sentences what I mean is that I am playing a video game from the Lord of the Rings franchise. In the second one, I mean I want to watch some parts from the Lord of the Rings movies.

Comment: The correct title of the trilogy is "**The** Lord of the Rings", but you are right that it would sound odd to include the article when using the phrase as an 'adjective' to describe a game based on it.

Comment: @KateBunting How about the second pair? Btw, even though it may sound weird, I think one could probably still use **the**. I don’t know.

Comment: Well, if I was intending to watch only a part of one of the films I would probably say "I want to watch some **of** _The Lord of the Rings_."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that, in casual conversation, we treat many titles that start with *the* this way. We delete the *the* if it is grammatically awkward:

> Here's your *[The] Princess Bride* DVD that I borrowed.
> I found some new *[The] Avengers* deleted scenes!

For that matter, casual conversation often routinely deletes the *the* from these titles even if it's *not* grammatically awkward: Stephen Colbert and friends [proudly declare](https://youtu.be/L1dU1HZ_73M) that "*Lord of the Rings* is the number-one 'trilly'."

This usage is unlikely to ruffle any reasonable feathers in all but the most formal, academic contexts. In those, it's best to reword the sentence so that the *the* is convenient:

> I returned his DVD of *The Princess Bride*.